# What is two or more drivers cross the chequered flag at the same time?

Tags: formula-1

At the 1997 European Grand Prix, three drivers - Jacques Villeneuve, Michael Schumacher and Heinz-Harald Frentzen - set identical times in qualifying. The FIA gave the pole to Villeneuve since he was the first driver to set the time. I can understand that.

What if this situation happened in a race where, on the last lap, two drivers reached the chequered flag at the same time. What would happen?

Would the winner be the person who had spent the most laps in the lead, or would it be the person who had qualified the furthest up the field?

Answer (score 4):

From the [2022 FIA Sporting regulations](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/formula_1_-_sporting_regulations_-_2022_-_iss_4_-_2022-02-18.pdf):

> 7.1 Prizes and points awarded for all the positions of Competitors who tie, will be added together and shared equally.

Both drivers would be classified as finishing in the first position and with the same time.  Not counting any other points gained (such as for fastest lap), both drivers would be awarded (25 + 18)/2 or 21.5 points.

Comment: May be worth adding that this has literally never happened in nearly 75 years of Formula One and, with timing down to the nearest millisecond, is believed to be virtually impossible.

Comment: Even NASCAR, which just by its nature typically has much closer finishes than Formula 1, hasn't had a tie since they introduced electronic timing in 1993.